# How to fix owl carousel problem with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sass

Here is the stacktrace:

> ```
> owl.carousel.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
>   at owl.carousel.min.js:6
>   at owl.carousel.min.js:6 (anonymous) @ owl.carousel.min.js:6 (anonymous) @ owl.carousel.min.js:6 index.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>   at index.js:1
> ```

Comment: Check the bottom of the stacktrace... It says that jQuery was not included in your page. >> _"`$ is not defined`"_

Comment: Make sure jQuery is loaded first before any jQuery-related scripts. Scripts load from top-down.

Answer (score 0):

Add the head section of your html to include jQuery from Google's CDN. A quick way to verify that the absence of jQuery is the source of the issue.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```